# How to create JCheckBox for elements of an HashMap

Tags: java, jquery, json, database, checkbox

I have an HashMap that fills in by a function in this mode:

```
private static Map<String, String> film = new HashMap<>();

   public static void init() {
   film.put(getIDFilm(), getTitle());
  }
```

Then each element of this Map will be a CheckBox. For example if the Map has 6 elements, it must create 6 checkboxes and it's important that I have the access to each single checkbox later, so I can specify for example:

```
if checkbox2 is selected, do this.
```

So is there any way to make these checkboxes dynamically according to the HashMap's size?

Comment: You can use an Iterator and a custom JCheckBox implementation that stores the Hashmap's key or key/value pair if it is needed for display.

Comment: You can use [`JCheckBox#setName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setName(java.lang.String)) to store the "IDFilm" with the `JCheckBox`.  The "name" field is typically used with GUI editors, but since you are dynamically creating the GUI yourself, the name fields is available for you to use.